# Suppress error message at DoDataExchange

Tags: validation, mfc

I want to suppress the MFC error message on data validation:

```
    void CMotorView::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
    {
        DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_AMBIENTTEMP, m_pSet->m_AmbientTemp);
    }
```

If the text in editcontrol `IDC_AMBIENTTEMP` is non numeric on saving data to variables, the framework will show a messagebox prompting the user to enter a number. I want to suppress this message, and handle the error in my own code.

I assumed the framework will throw an exception in case of validation error, but this appears not to be the case. Neither does `DDX_Text` return a value What am I doing wrong?

```
void CMotorView::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
   try
   {
       DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_AMBIENTTEMP, m_pSet->m_AmbientTemp);
   }
   catch(CUserException* ex)
   {
       // nothing caught here
   }
   catch(...)
   {
       // nothing caught here either
   }
}
```

Comment: Implement your own `MyDDX_Text` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of an error `DDX_Text` first displays an error dialog, then it throws an exception. You can catch this with `catch(CUserException *e)`. Please note that a pointer is thrown!

I'd suggest that you either DDX_Text to a string. This does not fail and you can then check if the string is really a number. Or you can write your own DDX_TextMyFn to do what you want. You can use the MFC original function as a base implementation.

Comment: You are right, I just forgot the * after CUserException (I typed the code right into the S.O. question form). In my test code I actually used CUserException*, so this is not the problem. Does this mean that what I want is not possible using standard MFC functions?

Comment: @Bart That is what I said. You can use DDX_Text and add your own number reading/writing or you can write a replacement for DDX_Text.

Answer (score 1):

Set ES_NUMBER as a style for the edit control. This will reduce errors user can make.

The message boxes inside the DDX routines can't be suppressed or redirected.

Here is some pseudocode that uses a class CEditInt that has a member unction GetValue/SetValue.

You can also write a DDX_EditInt routine that works on a CEdit control and use Get/SetDlgItemInt.

```
void AFXAPI DDX_EditInt(CDataExchange* pDX, int nIDC, int &iValue)
{
    // Get pointer to control
    HWND hWndCtrl = pDX->PrepareEditCtrl(nIDC);     
    CEditInt *pWnd = (CEditInt *)CWnd::FromHandle(hWndCtrl);
    // Must be an CEditInt
    ASSERT(pWnd->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(CEditInt)));
    // get the information from the defined window  
    if (pDX->m_bSaveAndValidate) 
        // Get the Value
        iValue = pWnd->GetValue();
    else 
        pWnd->SetValue(iValue);     
}
```

Comment: ES_NUMBER is set. Actually, my number is a floating point, not an integer. I for now will stick with Werner's solution instead of rolling some additional edit controls.